# Proper way to list a second heirarchy generator

Tags: python-3.x, list, generator

Let's say we have a generator that do operations on a generator, here's an example:

```
def print_forever(n): 
     while True:
         yield n 
  
def limit_gen(gen, n): 
     for i in range(n): 
         yield next(gen)
```

What's the proper way to insert the values of the generator in a list? `list(limit_gen(print_forever(2), 5)` for example raises a `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `print_forever` is instanciated once, then passed to the `limit_gen` one. After being called once, the first one has yield its one value and reach its own end, raising a StopIteration exception.

There are various ways to make it work, you could for example instanciate a new generator at each iteration:

```
def print_forever(v):
    yield v

def limit_gen(gen, v, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(gen(v))

for v in limit_gen(print_forever, 2, 5):
    print(v)
```

Another option is to make a *really* infinite generator:

```
def print_forever(v):
    while 1:
        yield v

def limit_gen(gen, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(gen)

for v in limit_gen(print_forever(2), 5):
    print(v)
```

Comment: If this is the 'insert in a list' part that is missing, you just have to replace the `for v in <expr>: print(v)` by `list(<expr>)`. If this is about something else, please have the courtesy to explain, as I took the time to answer... (also, you edited your question and added the second line of code since I answered. my answer is still relevant regarding to the original question)